# How to automate batch script for google app script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have multiple sheets and need to run scripts for more than 6 minutes. I have split the function such that each function call take less than 5 minutes. 
I have come across the blog http://patt0.blogspot.in/2014/08/continuous-batch-library-update-for.html to get around the 5-6 minute timeout. But I read in the same blog that userproperties service is deprecated now. Is there any update or any other way to accomplish the objective?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of userproperties,  use the Properties service now (the 'successor' of the depreciated userproperties and scriptproperties). It is even mentioned in the article you referred to. Documentation: [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties) and: [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service)

Answer (score 0):

http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/parallel +Bruce McPherson is your man on that topic.